# How to know the compression rate for 7-Zip?

Tags: c#, 7zip

I have the following code for creating split archives using 7zip.

**Compression level:** MX9

**Split archive size:** 1MB

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string zipFileName = @"D:\ZIP\zipfile.7z";
        string temp = @"D:\ZIP\ZM.pdf";
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"..\..\7za.exe";
        /**
          * Switch -mx0: Don't compress at all. This is called "copy mode."
          * Switch -mx1: Low compression. This is called "fastest" mode.
          * Switch -mx3: Fast compression mode. Will automatically set various parameters.
          * Switch -mx5: Same as above, but "normal."
          * Switch -mx7: This means "maximum" compression.
          * Switch -mx9: This means "ultra" compression.You probably want to use this.
          **/
        info.Arguments = string.Format("a -t7z \"" + zipFileName + "\" \"" + temp + "\" -v{0}k " + CompressionLevel.mx9, 1024);
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process process = Process.Start(info);
        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("Done zipping");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Normally for a 10MB file I get nine .7z files with extensions `.7z.001, .7z.002, .7z.003` and so on. So for a 1MB file, I get one .7z file with the extension `.7z.001`. What I want to achieve is to eliminate the `.001` extension if only a single file is generated. Is there any way to know how many split archives will be generated by 7zip based on its compression rate? I'm dealing with PDF files.

**EDIT:**

Basically what I want to do is to decide whether to create split archives or not. So I have to guess whether the resulting file will be greater than 1MB.

Comment: Why don't you just stop telling 7zip to split the archive? That should be a command line option. It is certainly an option in the main GUI.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yes I can remove the `V` option from the command line. What I want to know is the resulting file size.

Comment: That is difficult, and the performance might be comparable to just doing the compression and checking the resulting file size. You can make some guesses around known content, but other than that it's diminishing returns doing this sort of thing. Simply perform your compression and if you only count one file with a wildcard search of something like `.7z.*` then rename it manually cutting off the extension.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth That's actually a great suggestion. To cut the `.001` if only 1 file is found.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know what size the resulting files will have, unless you are able to analyze the content of the size and check how well it can be compressed. (Which can, to my knowledge, only be done by actually compressing it.)

For example, a PDF file containing only text might be better compressible than a file made up of only compressed images. The best solutions would be to stop splitting the archives, or to check for the presence of `.002`(etc.) files after compressing the input.

An alternative solution would be to compress the file in-memory using the C# LZMA sdk and then split the files manually if appropriate.

Comment: Well, I really have to split the archives as this would be sent over via Gmail which has a limit of 25 MB. For a file that is a little bit over 25 MB, I'm not really sure if it generates `a 25MB and a 1MB file` or `a 24 MB file` - everything depends on the compression rate. Checking for the presence of `.002` is actually great. Similar to what @AdamHouldsworth suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could try compressing various combinations of PDF files and averaging out the compression rate, and then you'd know the rough input size after which you'd end up with more than one archive.

That said, it won't be precise. A simpler thing would be to wait for 7-zip to finish, and then check how many files you have, and drop the `.001` if you only have one file.